# Incorrect mouse position on HTML canvas when having a navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

The position of mouse clicks on canvas is correct when I do not have a navigation bar. However, it shifted when I added a navigation bar at the top of the page.
Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row" style="display:none">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:5px;">...</nav>
      </div></div></div>

      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #d6d9dc; height:700px;">
         <div id="myimg" name="myimg"></div>
             <div id="canvasContainer" style="height:600px;">
             <canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute; background-color:#ecf0f1"></canvas>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Javascript for cursor position:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("canvasContainer");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

var x = "red",
    pixelSize = 2;

function make_base(image_url){
  image = new Image();
  image.src = image_url;

    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 600;
  canvas.style.background = 'url('+image.src+')';

  image.onload = function(){

   console.log("onload "+image.width)
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
  }
}

function color(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  if (obj === "white"){
    pixelSize = 16;
    x = "white";
  }else{
    x = obj.value;
    pixelSize = 2;
  }

}

function draw() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
  context.lineTo(currX, currY);
  context.strokeStyle = x;
  context.lineWidth = pixelSize;
  if(pixelSize == 16){
    context.clearRect(prevX, prevY, 14, 14);
  }else{
    context.stroke();
  }
  context.closePath();
}

function findxy(res, e) {
  if (res == 'down') {
      prevX = currX;
      prevY = currY;
      currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

      flag = true;
      dot_flag = true;
      if (dot_flag) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.fillStyle = x;
          context.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
          context.closePath();
          dot_flag = false;
      }
  }
  if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
      flag = false;
  }
  if (res == 'move') {
      if (flag) {
          prevX = currX;
          prevY = currY;
          currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
          currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
          draw();
      }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: check all css navbar

Comment: Could you also post the code you use to see the cursor position please

Comment: @jetpackpony, Thank you for the note - I added the js code for mouse cursor. I'll try to be more clear with my questions. Apologies for the inconvenience. :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce any problem so far. It could be something with the css. I've created a Pen (http://codepen.io/jetpackpony/pen/wgXKMP) please try and reproduce the problem there so we can have an isolated code sample

Comment: Also note that you have an extra closing div tag in your code: `</div></div></div>` on of those is not needed.

Comment: @jetpackpony I create a snipped here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egKdMB when I try the code on html file on my machine it reproduces the problem I have, but on Pen, the image does not show up so you can't draw on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mouse event properties `pageX`, `pageY` they give you the position of the mouse relative to the top left of the page. You then get the position of the element you have the mouse events on with `event.target.getBoundingClientRect`. Then you need to remove the scroll offset the page may be at.

At this stage you have the mouse position to the top left of the element. You have one issue left and that is the element's border width. If you have the border width in pixels then subtract that as well from the `mouse.x`, `mouse.y` pos, if the border is using a different metric and or the top and left borders are different sizes you will have to make the appropriate adjustment.

```
var mouse = {x : 0, y : 0, events : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup"};
function mouseEvent(e) {
    var bounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;  // is window.scrollX same for Y
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;   // 
}

mouse.events    // chaining functions
    .split(",")
    .forEach((eName) => {
        canvas.addEventListener(eName,mouseEvent)
    });
```

For older browsers you will need to get the scroll position via.

```
// add this to the mouse event listeners.
var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");

var currentScrollX = supportPageOffset ? window.pageXOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft;
var currentScrollY = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
```

From [MDN web API scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY#Notes)

Comment: This works for me. The only problem is that I can't scroll the window because the mouse position on the canvas is shifted as well. If you know how to fix that, it would be great, but if not, it's fine. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @matchifang Sorry I do not understand what mean by the mouse is "shifted as well"?

Comment: uh? evt.clientY === evt.pageY - (scrollY || pageYOffset)

Comment: You're welcome ;-) But what I meant beside that `scrollY` is not supported in IE (btw `pageYOffset` is supported since IE9, just like canvas API, so no need for the <IE9 polyfill), is that `evt.clientY` is already the same as `evt.pageY - scrollY` so no need to calculate it yourself, it's in the event, and this since IE6. But for OP's problem, I'm clueless... but I don't know bootscrap enough to know exactly what all these rules are actually doing to the viewport.

Comment: @Kaiido I have taken to using pageX, and pageY and listen to document mouse events to handle a global mouse object. It lets you move off the browser tab and window and still get mouse up, move, and wheel if mouse still down, which normal DOM elements will not do. When I use clientX,clientY i get a 1 pixel wide dead zone on the left where the page crosses over to the Win10 task bar that returns 0,0 which is very annoying . (only on FF).